# Schedule a GPS location check daily at a predefined time in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-service, alarmmanager, schedule

I'm from an iOS background with intermediate Android knowledge. Anyways for this task, I need to know what exactly I need to work with. My app needs to check if the user is at or close to the predefined location at a predefined time. Getting user location is not an issue.

My guess is working with a combination of `AlarmManager`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` ? I haven't worked with either of these three.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the ingredients you need for you recipe:

An `Intent` that targets your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourBroadCastReceiver.class);
```

A `PendingIntent` that gets triggered by the `AlarmManager` and fires your already defined `Intent`:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags);
```

The `AlarmManager` that periodically activates your `PendingIntent`:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
```

The `BroadCastReceiver` that handles the event:

```
@Override
protected void handleReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // handle GPS
}
```

Comment: @Martin no need of creating a service running in the background?

Comment: No need for a Service, the combination you proposed and I described suits your goal perfectly.

Comment: so If I'm right I set the intent, pendingIntent and AlarmManager on say click of an "enable button"? Also, wont this fire and display the activity at the specified time?

Comment: That is correct. The activity will not display if you don't tell it to display. Your `BroadCastReceiver` can work in the background.

Comment: It works. Accepting your answer. On a Sidenote, I wanted to check for location updates at a fixed time, but as of Android ICS and above, GPS cannot be forced to be ON, and user has to be redirected to Settings. Since this a background operation, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You will have to ask the user to manually activate the GPS settings, you can not do this by code due security issues.